# Object Assign clonando propriedades undefinied

Tags: javascript

Preciso clonar meu array de Objetos de modo que as propriedades undefined não sobrescreva uma propriedade ja existente.

```js
const myArray = [

    {
        "tecnico": "INS-MAN-RENAN M/RENAN C",
        "horas": "08:30:00",
        "2021-04-18": "21.94502"
    },
    {
        "tecnico": "INS-MAN-RENAN M/RENAN C",
        "horas": "08:30:00",
        "2021-04-18": ""
    },
    {
        "tecnico": "INS-MAN-RENAN M/RENAN C",
        "horas": "08:30:00",
        "2021-04-23": ""
    },
  
]

console.log(Object.assign({}, ...myArray));
```

Eu preciso obter o seguinte Resultado:

```js
{
  "tecnico": "INS-MAN-RENAN M/RENAN C",
  "horas": "08:30:00",
  "2021-04-18": "21.94502",
  "2021-04-23": ""
}
```

Comment: Não é clonar o que procura. Não seria reduzir a um elemento? Se for mesmo reduzir qual o critério de escolha dos dados no caso de chaves já povoadas com valores diferentes. Exemplo: Se houver dois objetos no array cujo a chave *hora* estiverem assim `{"horas": "08:30:00"}, {"horas": "12:00:00"}` ?

Comment: Seria clonar pois as chaves repetidas serão reduzidas a um objeto como no caso acima e as que não forem serão inseridas no mesmo objeto ... o problema é quando encontra uma chave igual mas com um valor indefinido e acaba sobrescrevendo o valor anterior, como no caso da data 2021-04-18

Comment: Repito não é clonar é reduzir, veja o exemplo https://ideone.com/eSk8Rm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A idea de usar `...myArray` no `Object.assign` é boa mas como reparaste vis sempre sobrepor valores antigos com os novos, e acabas por sobrepor o valor que queres por uma string vazia.

Tens de criar um `reducer` que verifique se já há um valor definido e se o novo valor que vais definir é uma string vazia ou não.
Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
const myArray = [{
    "tecnico": "INS-MAN-RENAN M/RENAN C",
    "horas": "08:30:00",
    "2021-04-18": "21.94502"
  },
  {
    "tecnico": "INS-MAN-RENAN M/RENAN C",
    "horas": "08:30:00",
    "2021-04-18": ""
  },
  {
    "tecnico": "INS-MAN-RENAN M/RENAN C",
    "horas": "08:30:00",
    "2021-04-23": ""
  },
]

const merge = (arr) => arr.reduce((obj, entry) => {
  for (const key in entry) {
    if (typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined' && entry[key] === '') continue
    obj[key] = entry[key]
  }
  return obj

}, {})

console.log(merge(myArray))
```

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, realmente utilizando o reduce e verificando as keys com valores undefined resolveu o meu problema.  Imaginei que através do Object Assign, keys com valores undefined fosse ignoradas.

Comment: Boa! Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite